malformed entry in sources.list
I cannot do anything with "apt", as I am getting:
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor-project.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
I was able to copy the contents of the list file, although the line numbers did not copy with the content...so I listed the empty line numbers below the content, below.
I am not a new user, but am not expert, either....so I understand the error and found the file, but do not know what to do to fix this (plus, although I am using the ubuntu text editor and I am the only user and installer of this rev 22.04, i do not have permission to edit the file and do not know what to do to change that). thanks in advance for any help, as I sure need some:
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Jammy Jellyfish - Release amd64 (20230807.2)]/ jammy main restricted
See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
This system was installed using small removable media
(e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
For information about how to configure apt package sources,
see the sources.list(5) manual.
the line spaces represent lines 2,7,12,20,30,38 and 45 (these numbers won't copy out of the list file)
again, thanks so much....

this posting did not format well....the large text are the contents of the list fileso sorry
the spaces represent lines 2,7,12,20,30,38 and 45 (these numbers won't copy out of the list file

i apologize for the formatting issue...the text above is the contents of the list file

i saw that answer previously, but do not know how to apply it directly to my own problem. to wit, it mentions "trusty", I have no clue what that is, and I would never have posted this question, after i looked carefully for a helpful answer, if I had found one. I need, please, step by step advice which pertains to my particular situation and file. thank you.

furthermore, I have recently had lung cancer surgery and am simply too tired to spend hours trying to tailor an answer from someone referring to a different system...where some comma or character difference might prevent me from a solution or even make things worse...so I respectfully ask that you reopen the question and let someone give me the kind of real guidance I need. thank you

this is also why I took time to point out that I am not new but lack real expertise....I cannot finesse my way thru this, especially given my health problems at this time.

Re-read the error message. You posted the wrong file.

thank you. after a night's sleep, i see that now. the correct file (I think), is: Computer/etc/apt/sources.list.d  that takes me to: tor-project.list.  when i go to try to change it, it indicates I am not the owner. I attempted to use 'chmod 777' but got the same response. however, I see the line that the error message says is the problem. what, please, do you suggest I do next? thanks so much!

ps i tried, here, to post the contents of 'tor-project.list" but this Q&A utility says "too many characters". would you like me to post it in two sections?

We don't need to see the entire "tor-project.list". YOU need to see it. Specifically you need to edit Line 2 of that file to fix whatever the error is. You have plenty of examples of what a correct entry should look like. Another option is to remove your Tor sources and cease using Tor until your health improves.

ok....although for some reason (please advance an opinion if you feel like doing so), I was not previously able to delete the file, now I could and just did. it is gone and so is the error message. i can also now do an apt update as it should be but could not be when this error existed. also, that I could not modify permissions to edit the file, with terminal indicating that I was not the owner...is this a micro result of this individual problem, or is there a more global reason, and if so, what, please, do you suggest I can do about that (for next time, if nothing else)? tnx
